# 2-D array not being initialized properly

Tags: c++, arrays

Simple one line stopping code from compiling, what is wrong?

```
char *words[256] = new char[numOfWords][256];

array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

Comment: `words` is not a 2D array, but an array of 256 `char*`. As C++, why not use a `std::vector<string>` or `std::array<256, std::string>` ?

Comment: I want an array with numOfWords char[256], am i doing this backwards?  Trying to do this without any stl

Comment: A bit more context to the question i.e. code snippets to explain may be useful.  Do you want an array of the numOfWords? But you seem to be declaring an array of 256 elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared an array of 256 pointers to `char`. The error message is clear - arrays need to be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer. So if you want to keep your declaration, do this:

```
char* words[256] = { new char[wordlength], ... };
       //   ^^^ this is effectively your numOfWords
```

Alternatively, you can leave out the initialization altogether and assign individual elements later, say in a loop. Note that, if you allocate elements dynamically, you're also responsible for deleting them properly.

If you want a pointer to an array of arrays of 256 `char`s, then this:

```
char (*words)[256] = new char[numOfWords][256];
```

Comment: or perhaps: char* words[256] = {new char[numOfWords]};

Comment: @Xploit Could be, but OP's comment above suggests otherwise, IMO.

Comment: Thanks! Works!  My reverse words function is now a success :)

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a 2D array, think of it as simply an array of pointers to other arrays. Thus, to do what you are asking:

```
char *words[] = new char*[256];
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    words[i] = new char[numOfWords];
}
```